# Library types in Stanley Lipmann's "C++ Primer"

Tags: c++

Newbie to C++ but I am a Java programmer. Trying to learn C++ now. Reading the C++ Primer by Stanley Lipmann.

I don't understand this sentence in Chapter 3 about library types. He's talking about library type string and vector:

> These library types are abstractions of more primitive types - arrays and pointers - that are part of the language

Could it be he meant:

> These library types are abstraction type rather than primitive types like arrays and pointers which are part of the language

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Hahaha sounds to me like he's confusing readers with overly complicated syntax.

On topic, I'd say a vector is kind of a type of abstraction from an array, a string is essentially the same thing, as an array of characters...

Comment: The two statements are equivalent, yes.

Comment: If you're a newbie, then you don't need to understand EACH and EVERY WORD of the book you read. You just keep reading, and go ahead with whatever you understand at the moment. Once you understand the basic of the language, then you can start reading it again to understand what you didn't understand earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen a very good book but I can see where the sentence could confuse you.

I think this:

> "These library types are abstractions of more primitive types - arrays and pointers - that are part of the language"

Should say something more like this:

"These library types are **extensions** of more primitive types - arrays and pointers - that are part of the language"

Comment: Given OP's Java background, where supposedly "everything is an object" and the connotation of inheritance associated with the `extends` keyword in Java, I would suspect this will confuse OP even more.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I think your wording makes more sense than the author.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more cultural than it is technical.

The author seems to consider things like pointers and arrays for primitive data types because they map very closely to the machine architecture (an array is a contiguous block of memory, a pointer is a memory address). Of course, what he is calling library types all use memory, and all have an address in the memory space, but also build into it a lot of complex logic and behavior not inherent in the system architecture. That's why he calls it an abstraction type.

To old school students of C++, you always learned from the bottom up. That is you start with the more primitive data types (and how they map to the machine) and slowly move to more abstracted classes (like strings, lists, etc).

To new Java students, everything is an object - with all the advanced memory management, error checking, complex functions one could hope for. The notion of a set of data types that are "primitive" are sort of taken out of Java so that the distinction of "abstractedness" is kind of moot.

Good Luck with your C++ endeavors :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me give an example. `int  p[5];` is an array declaration, whereas `std::vector<int> v;` is a `vector` library type declaration. They both can be accessed as `p[index]` (or `v[index]`, respectively), but their behaviour is different: reading an array value is just accessing memory at some location, reading `vector` mean range checking and such, it can be resized, but an array can't, etc.